# error while compiling ffmpeg: gcc is unable to create an executable file

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, ffmpeg

When I run the `./configure` command in ffmpeg source directory I get this error:

```
gcc is unable to create an executable file. If gcc is a cross-compiler, use the --enable-cross-compile option. Only do this if you know what cross compiling means. C compiler test failed.

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net. Include the log file "config.log" produced by configure as this will help solving the problem.
```

in config.log:

```
check_ld cc
check_cc
BEGIN /tmp/ffconf.xECiIX7z.c
    1   int main(void){ return 0; }
END /tmp/ffconf.xECiIX7z.c
gcc -c -o /tmp/ffconf.xsCaoMWN.o /tmp/ffconf.xECiIX7z.c
gcc -o /tmp/ffconf.ApzYq7NQ /tmp/ffconf.xsCaoMWN.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `__libc_csu_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `__libc_csu_init'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
C compiler test failed.
```

What's wrong? What should I do?

Comment: Take a hint from "include the config.log".

Comment: Please see the edited post

Comment: What operating system is this? Is this the GCC that came with the OS? Are you running a 32-bit or 64-bit version of the OS? Did you pass any arguments to `./configure`?

Comment: how do you make? did you `./configure` ? if true What's your distro? `uname -a`

Comment: @Gilles: Ubuntu 64-bit. I don't pass any arguments to ./configure

Comment: Just curious, but what is the advantage of compiling `ffmpeg` fom source? I thought it's already in the repo and there's `livav` pre-installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your libc installation is incomplete or broken somehow. You should say what OS you use... the easiest fix is probably to reinstall the packages that comprise the libc.

Or if you are really interested in finding out exactly which part of it is broken, here are some tips:

On a typical glibc installation, the references to `__libc_csu_init` and `__libc_csu_fini` will be resolved by finding them in `/usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a` which you can check as follows:

```
$ nm /usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a | egrep '__libc_csu_(init|fini)'
0000000000000000 T __libc_csu_fini
0000000000000010 T __libc_csu_init
```

The use of `/usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a` will be triggered by linking to `/usr/lib/libc.so` (which is a text file, not an actual shared object). You can check that like this:

There may be some other stuff in it too. You can check that with

```
$ less /usr/lib/libc.so
[...]
GROUP ( /lib/libc.so.6 /usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a )
```

`/usr/lib/libc.so` will be used by the linker to satisfy the `-lc` requirement, which you can check like this:

```
$ ld --verbose -lc
[... lots of stuff ...]
opened script file /usr/lib64/libc.so
attempt to open /lib/libc.so.6 succeeded
/lib/libc.so.6
attempt to open /usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a succeeded
```

Comment: How do I reinstall glibc? `apt-get install(remove) glibc` says there is no package named glibc

Comment: `apt-get install --reinstall libc6`

Comment: I'm getting same error in windows 8, Any help?

Answer (score 6):

That means you don't have the necessary software to compile C code.

Run this:

```
apt-get install build-essential
```

You also want the build dependencies for ffmpeg:

```
apt-get build-dep ffmpeg
```

Then try again.

Comment: Unfortunately still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I had a problem with similar symptoms  recently while compiling ffmpeg on my workstation. What caused the problem was passing several flags to enable the opus and vpx codecs, which appears to influence the flags passed into `gcc`. In my case these libraries weren't present yet and the `./configure` was detecting that `gcc` didn't produce an executable with those flags. In this case the error `gcc is unable too create an executable` was insufficient.

Comment: I removed some flags and ffmpeg was able to build! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you may get an error while installing FFMPEG on centOS 6.5,

create repo :   **/etc/yum.repos.d/dag.repo**

```
# vi  /etc/yum.repos.d/dag.repo
```

add below lines into it,

```
[dag]
name=DAG RPM Repository
baseurl=http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el$releasever/en/$basearch/dag
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
```

GPG key for DAG, run the below command,

```
# rpm --import http://apt.sw.be/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt
```

Now update and install ffmpeg,

```
# yum update
# yum install ffmpeg ffmpeg-devel ffmpeg-libpostproc
```